# GDB pretty-printer: printing an array when the size is known by the parent struct

Tags: python, debugging, gdb, pretty-print, gdb-python

I have a struct in C++ something like this:

```
struct HeapBlock {
    char* data;
}

struct DataBlock {
    int size;
    HeapBlock hb;
}
```

These are part of a framework and have several other members, helpers and so on, but these are are the important parts. I would like to show this in a Python GDB pretty-printer something like this:

```
NAME                  TYPE             VALUE
DataBlock:            DataBlock       "Size 2000 @ 0x445343"
  |--->size           int             2000
  |--->data           HeapBlock       {...}
        |--->[0]      char            0x34
        |--->[1]      char            0x45
        ....
        <more values>
```

So far, I have failed at getting the HeapBlock to be shown as a separate child. I have successfully abused an iterator to produce:

```
NAME                  TYPE             VALUE
DataBlock:            DataBlock      
  |--->size           int              2000
  |--->[0]            char             0x34
  |--->[1]            char             0x45
   ....
   <more values>
```

This was done by returning the `db["size"]` in the first result from the iterator returned by `DataBlockPrinter`'s `children()` method, and then from `db["hb"]["data"]` for the next `size` results.

I have also tried to use a separate printer for `HeapBlocks`, but the problem there is that a `HeapBlock` has no idea how big it is: that is stored in the parent (`DataBlock`), so the `HeapBlock` printer also doesn't know when to stop iterating.

Is it possible to get the `size` field to the `HeapBlock` pretty printer when it is printed as part of `DataBlock` here?

Answer (score 1):

I found another way

```
#convert to vector
class DataBlock:
  def iter(self):
    p=self.v['p']
    emtp=p.type.target().unqualified().strip_typedefs()
    pv=emtp.vector(self.cnt-1).pointer()#convert to vector,the actual type is char (*) __attribute__ (vector_size(self.cnt)))
    yield('p',p.cast(pv))
#We register this type
def regCls(v):
    if str(v.type).find(") __attribute__ ((vector_size")>0:
      return _py_vector(v)
def regMyPP():gdb.pretty_printers.append(regCls) 
#Then parse this type out
class _py_vector:
  def __init__(self,v):self.v=v
  def tp(self):
    s=str(self.v.type)
    return gdb.lookup_type(s[:s.find('(')-1]).pointer()#eg.char
  def sz(self):
    s=str(self.v.type)
    st=s.find('vector_size(')+12
    ed=s.find(')',st)
    return int(s[st:ed])#Get it's size
  def to_string(self): return self.v.cast(self.tp()).lazy_string(length=self.sz())
  def display_hint(self): return 'string'
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no built-in way to do this.  I believe there is a bug open about it in gdb bugzilla.

It might be possible to do it with a hack: in the `DataBlock` printer, record the address and size of the `HeapBlock` in a hash table.  Then the `HeapBlock` printer could look this up.  Of course then the problem becomes one of deciding how to invalidate the cache.  Offhand I can't think of a good way :-(  But maybe it's ok to simply not invalidate it.  You might try invalidating when the `DataBlock` printer is destroyed; gdb doesn't guarantee that this will work, but it might be ok in practice.

Comment: Seems like a combination of https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=12806 and https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16436?